# GROUP_CONCAT with LEFT OUTER JOIN of two tables

Tags: php, sql, left-join, group-concat

```
SELECT table1.value, table2.additionalinfo
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.ID=table2.ID
```

I try to output something like this

```
Value   AdditionalInfo
blah    something, somethingelse, more
blah2   NULL
blah3   stuff
```

but I get

```
Value   AdditionalInfo
blah    something
blah    somethingelse
blah    more
blah2   NULL
blah3   stuff
```

I tried to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT)`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table1.value), table2.additionalinfo
FROM table1
left outer JOIN table2
ON table1.ID=table2.ID ORDER BY table1.value
```

When I add `GROUP_CONCAT` and `ORDER BY table1.value` it lists just one additionalinfo per value but none of the values and doesn't get the repeated additionalinfos. I moved the order by all around to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do `GROUP_CONCAT` on `AdditionalInfo` Column and not on `table1.value`

```
SELECT table1.value, 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct table2.additionalinfo) additionalinfo
FROM table1
left outer JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table2.ID 
GROUP BY table1.value
ORDER BY table1.value
```